# Is my SSD hard disk broken?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

In September 2009 I bought a Crucial M225 128GB 2.5" SATA-II SSD. I have been running Windows 7 64 bits in the SSD disk for two years.

Last week I began to get some errors. chkdsk was delivering some errors at boot time but it seemed able to recover. But after a couple of days with these weird errors I got a blue screen in Windows during startup just after the Windows Logo is loaded. Windows blue screen show a STOP error 0x00000050 (PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA).

It seems I was suffering the same problem as described in the Super Site question [Getting a Stop error on vista boot page fault in nonpaged area question](https://superuser.com/questions/97112/getting-a-stop-error-on-vista-boot-page-fault-in-nonpaged-area)

[image: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA Blue Screen error]

I checked if it was a RAM Issue.

- Run a memory test using the diagnostic tool - passed
- Run a memtest86+ and I did not get any memory errors.

So, I thought my only chance was to reinstall Windows 7. I backed up important files and reinstalled the OS. Everything run fine for the first 24 hours but after a couple of boots I began getting errors. I run chkdsk in my SSD disk with the repair option and I got several errors:

[image: chkdsk errors]

**It is safe to assume that there is no other solution than replacing the SSD disk because it is going to keep failing?**

Comment: FYI, "SSD" is an abbreviation of "Solid State Disk", so "SSD disk" or even "SSD hard disk" do not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

(This is only an answer to the first part of the question)

This is apparently an error generated by a USB device

Spurce: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979538/en

The page includes a hotfix that you should apply.

Hotfix page: http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=979538&kbln=en-us